# Background color of divs that were changed with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Can anyone suggest how to set a full background color to a div which is aligned with flexbox?

Here is how I set it up:

[image]

```
.small-box {
    width: 26%;
    background-color: #282c34;
    overflow: auto;
}

.main-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the HTML? With just CSS and screen shots, we're just guessing. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Probably the issue is due to the fact that you're setting the width to 26%. You need to make the small boxs 1/3 of the width of the container each.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, it was the mistake to set it so 26%...

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width: 26%;`

```css
.small-box {
  background-color: #282c34;
  overflow: auto;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.main-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
  <div class="small-box">
    This is some test text. This is some test text. This is some test text. This is some test text. This is some test text.
  </div>
  <div class="small-box">
    This is some test text. This is some test text. This is some test text. This is some test text. This is some test text.
  </div>
  <div class="small-box">
    This is some test text. This is some test text. This is some test text. This is some test text. This is some test text.
  </div>
</div>
```